# Unable to get data from a div tag using HTML parsing (hpple) in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, hpple

I am trying to parse the below link using hpple:

http://www.decanter.com/news/wine-news/529748/mimimum-pricing-opponents-slam-cameron-speech

Code:

```
- (void)parseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];    
    TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
    NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"<div class=\"body\" id=\"article-529748-body\">"];
    NSLog(@"elements %@",elements);
    TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *myTitle = [element content];
    [xpathParser release];
}
```

but it is crashing. Crash Report:

```
XPath error : Invalid expression
<div class="body" id="article-529748-body">
^
XPath error : Invalid expression
<div class="body" id="article-529748-body">
^
```

How to solve this issue? why my elements array is empty? Am I parsing in a wrong way? I want to get the information available in that div tag.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your elements array is not empty

```
- (void)parseURL:(NSURL *)url {
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];    
TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"<div class=\"body\" id=\"article-529748-body\">"];
NSLog(@"elements %@",elements);
if([elements count]){
    TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
}
NSString *myTitle = [element content];
[xpathParser release];
}
```

Comment: @Dee Try to parse a simple HTML file like "http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html"  using same code. If you can parse it then the problem will be with hpple. Unlike XML, HTML is  not as much easy to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"<div class=\"body\" id=\"article-529748-body\">"];
```

To:

```
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//div [@class='body'] [@id=\'article-529748-body\']"];
```

Comment: This was how it's done on Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on how to parse HTML on iOS. I also know that Obj - C sometimes flips out when you forget to put a @ in front of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Writing this (2 years later!) in case it's useful to someone else with a similar problem.

In order to parse the html within the div, you need to

1. use syntax *similar* (single-quotes don't need to be escaped) to that quoted by JamMySon on this page
2. remember that [element content] only gives you the content( if any) for that node , NOT its children.

Because of this you may need to use recursion to walk though the div's node-tree.

Code (ARC):

```
- (void) decanterHpple{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.decanter.com/news/wine-news/529748/mimimum-pricing-opponents-slam-cameron-speech"];
    NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    TFHpple *pageParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:htmlData];

    NSString *queryString = @"//div[@id='article-529748-body']";//1.works with unescaped single-quotes(') AND 2.No need for class='' when using id=''
    NSArray *elements = [pageParser searchWithXPathQuery:queryString];

    //old code ~ slightly amended
    if([elements count]){
        TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *myTitle = [element content];
        NSLog(@"myTitle:%@",myTitle );
    }
    //new code
    NSString *theText = [self stringFromWalkThruNodes:elements];
    NSLog(@"theText:%@",theText );
}
```

using this recursive method:

```
- (NSString*) stringFromWalkThruNodes:(NSArray*) nodes {
    static int level = 0;//level is only useful for keeping track of recursion when stepping through with a breakpoint
    level++;//put breakpoint here...
    NSString *text = @"";
    for (TFHppleElement *element in nodes){
        if (element.content) {
            text = [text stringByAppendingString:element.content];
        }
        if (element.children) {
            NSString *innerText = [self stringFromWalkThruNodes:element.children];
            text = [text stringByAppendingString:innerText];
        }
    }
    level--;
    return text;
}
```

This gives the output:

> 2014-10-22 19:44:07.996 Decanted[10148:a0b] myTitle:(null)
>
> 2014-10-22 19:44:07.997 Decanted[10148:a0b] theText:
>
> On a visit to a hospital in north-east England, Mr Cameron is to call for the drinks industry to do more to tackle a problem which
>   costs the National Health Service £2.7bn a year.A ban on the sale of
>   alcohol below cost price - less than the tax paid on it - is set to be
>   introduced in England and Wales from 6 April, but ministers are
>   expected to push for a higher minimum price for drink.Opponents of a
>   minimum unit price say it is unfair because it penalises all drinkers,
>   not just binge or problem drinkers.Responding to the Prime Minister’s
>   comments, Wine and Spirit Trade Association spokesman Gavin Partington
>   reiterated the drinks indusry’s commitment ‘to helping the Government
>   tackle alcohol misuse, alongside other stakeholders.‘This is why we
>   are working hard through the Public Health Responsibility Deal on a
>   range of initiatives to promote responsible drinking.’These
>   initiatives, Partington said, include the expansion of Community
>   Alcohol Partnerships across the UK and a national campaign by
>   retailers to raise consumer awareness about the units of alcohol in
>   alcoholic drinks.Partington said, ‘Unlike these measures, minimum unit
>   pricing is a blunt tool which would both fail to address the problem
>   of alcohol misuse and punish the vast majority of responsible
>   consumers. As Government ministers acknowledge, it is also probably
>   illegal'.Decanter is also against the scheme, calling it
>   ‘fundamentally flawed.’‘The real problem,’ editor Guy Woodward has
>   said, ‘lies with supermarkets who use wine as a loss-leader, slashing
>   margins, bullying suppliers and dragging down prices in order to
>   attract customers…Selling wine at a loss helps neither consumers nor
>   the trade.’Other opponents of the scheme include the British Beer and
>   Pub Association, which told the BBC there was ‘a danger it would be
>   done through higher taxation, which would be hugely damaging to
>   pub-goers, community pubs and brewers, costing thousands of vital
>   jobs.’It is thought any move toward minimum pricing could also be
>   illegal under European competition law, which is aimed at pushing down
>   prices for consumers and allowing firms to operate in a free
>   market.

PS. Only started playing with Hpple this p.m. after reading the aforementioned [Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios); I'm sure someone more experienced may come up with a more elegant solution!