# Get table data from html using hpple

Tags: ios, objective-c, xpath, hpple

I am trying to parse the following website so I display the data like this on iOS:

**Saturday 6th September**

Causeway
Bond's Glen Raceway
11:00am
RO
Two Day Meeting
Two Separate Days

An example of the website:

```
    <div id="main-column">
<h1>September</h1>
    <table align="center"><col width="200"><col width="150"><col width="100"><col width="120"><col width="330"><col width="300">
        <h2>Saturday 06 September</h2>
        <tr id="table1">
            <td><b>Club</b></td>
            <td><b>Venue</b></td>
            <td><b>Start Time</b></td>
            <td><b>Meeting Type</b></td>
            <td><b>Number of Days for Meeting</b></td>
            <td><b>Notes</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="table2">
            <td>Causeway</td>
            <td>Bond's Glen Raceway</td>
            <td>11:00am</td>
            <td>RO</td>
            <td>Two Day Meeting,<br> Two Separate Days</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="table3">
            <td>West Waterford</td>
            <td>Ballysaggart</td>
            <td>11:00am</td>
            <td>RO</td>
            <td>Two Day Meeting,<br> One Meeting Over Two Days</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
```

So far I have managed to get all of the dates with the following code:

```
    -(void)loadData {

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.national-autograss.co.uk/september.htm"];
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];


TFHpple *htmlParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:htmlData];


NSString *xpathQueryString = @"//h2";
NSArray *eventNodes = [htmlParser searchWithXPathQuery:xpathQueryString];



NSMutableArray *eventDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for (TFHppleElement *element in eventNodes) {

    NSString *date = [[element firstChild] content];
    [eventDates addObject:date];

}

_objects = eventDates;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

Is the Xpath query I need for the data in the table something like //table/tr/td? I tried this and I got an immediate error of adding a nil object to an array.

Or am I better to get all of the tables as separate elements and then parse individually for the data inside?

Any help, guides or ideas would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently gave [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333739/unable-to-get-data-from-a-div-tag-using-html-parsing-hpple-in-iphone/26515076#26515076) to an old hpple question.

Changing the URL to the autograss site and the query string to...

```
NSString *queryString = @"//table";
```

...in order to get the closest ancestor of the required text-nodes gives this log output:

> 2014-10-28 11:52:02.416 SiteSearcher[28314:613] theText:
>
> ```
>           Saturday 06 September
>
>               Club
>                 Venue
>                 Start Time
>                 Meeting Type
>                 Number of Days for Meeting
>                 Notes
>
>
>                 Causeway
>                 Bond's Glen Raceway
>                 11:00am
>                 RO
>                 Two Day Meeting, Two Separate Days
>
>
>
>                 West Waterford
>                 Ballysaggart
>                 11:00am
>                 RO
>                 Two Day Meeting, One Meeting Over Two Days
>
>
>             Sunday 07 September...
> ```

but also gives

```
        ...2014 Fixtures:
            January
            February
            March
            April
            May
            June


            2014 Fixtures Cont'd:
            July
            August
            September
            October
            November
            December


            Official Details:
            Regisitered Address:
                46 Brookside, Alconbury,
                Huntingdonshire, PE28 2EP.
```

...as it retrieves *all* the tables.

(Please excuse colouring - the log output tabs seem to mess up blockQuotes!).

I don't whether having the text with all the clutter is that useful, but maybe it's a start. If , however, you wish to assign segments of the text to,say, array elements for some TableView then the recursion would need adapting.

**Update**

After looking at answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588888/hpple-xpath-query-for-complex-html),  I realise that some tidying can be made by using a conditional query:

```
NSString *xPathQueryString = @"//tr[not(@id='table1')]|//h2";
```

or

```
NSString *xPathQueryString = @"//h2/text()|//tr[not(@id='table1')]//td/text()";
```

The first query pulls the element-nodes whereas the second pulls the text nodes themselves. The second, therefore, needs no recursive method to delve within tags but (as far as I can see) brings no further info such as parent tag.

Comment: Thats a great help cate. I ended up having to pull all of the td data and do some trickery to get rid of the references for the empty cells and work out where I was in the document by the amount of null references I had already seen. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Harg; it may be worth looking at other q's tagged with hpple  to glean hints - I've found very little around on how to construct queries. In order to make data a bit more manipulable, method could be changed to use `element.parent.tagName` to add a `@"date": [NSMutableArray]` key-value to a global dictionary foreach new date and append that array foreach `<td>` text.